# How to use FB auth and Cloudant to mount a db per user architecture?

Tags: couchdb, facebook-authentication, cloudant

I am needing to extend my app to allow users account. After to analyze the three options here (https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/PerDocumentAuthorization) I will follow the per user DB strategy.

To handle the auth I will use Twitter, FB and "manual registration". However I am not finding related documentation with examples.

The user database will contain information that will help me to user better the push notification and store personal information about the users.

Anyone can help me with references in how I can achieve it?

Thanks

Comment: best to ask Cloudant about how to do the auth setup with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that there seems to be a lack of sample applications in this area. The idea is that upon registration your app will

- create a new database for that user - PUT /$DATABASE (https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html#create)
- create an api key/password that allows read/write access for that user - PUT /_api/v2/db/$DATABASE/_security - (https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html#authorization)
- store (in a Cloudant databases) the relationship between your user (the Twitter id, or handle) and the the database name you created for them
- communicate the database name, api key and password securely to the device that will be making requests

e.g.

```
{
  "twitter": "glynn_bird",
  "database": "abc123"
 }
```

If in the future, the user authenticates from another device, you should be able to establish that they have created an account before and point them to their pre-existing database, issuing a fresh api key & password in the process.